# "Get" request method not working in vba

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I've written a code to fetch the name
of a restaurant using its phone number applying
"GET" http method but what i'm doing wrong
with this process is beyond my knowledge. So, if anybody extends a helping
hand to resolve this issue, i would be very grateful to him.
Thanks in advance.

```
Sub test()

Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, myHtml As New HTMLDocument
Dim PostData As String, ele As Object, thing As Object
Dim x As Long

x = 2

PostData = "what=5197365924"
xmlhttp.Open "GET", "http://mobile.canada411.ca/search/" & PostData, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
xmlhttp.send
myHtml.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText


Set ele = myHtml.getElementsByClassName("merchant-title__name jsShowCTA")

For Each thing In ele
    Cells(x, 1) = thing.innertext
    x = x + 1
Next thing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of issues were there in my post. However, I've fixed it already. Now, it is good to go.

```
Sub reverse_search()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim ArgumentString As String, post As Object

    ArgumentString = "what=5197365924&where=Canada&redirect=reversetobusiness"

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.yellowpages.ca/bus/Ontario/Amherstburg/Downtown-Expresso-Cafe/522901.html?" & ArgumentString, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each post In html.getElementsByClassName("merchant-title__name")
        x = x + 1: Cells(x, 1) = post.innerText
    Next post
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is pretty fine, but your endpoint does not show anything, you can test in your browser and you will see.

I suggest you read the [YellowAPI doc](http://www.yellowapi.com/docs/places/#findbusiness) and test this kind of [endpoint](http://api.yellowapi.com/FindBusiness/?what=5197365924&where=Canada&fmt=XML&pgLen=10&apikey=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&UID=YOUR_UID_HERE), changing the values `YOUR_API_KEY_HERE` and `YOUR_UID_HERE`.

Comment: Yeah i understood what you have said but i would like to go one step ahead to get it done not using API rather, with the way i started it. Should have alternatives through which i can reach the destination and scrape what i want because you know i'm getting redirected with this code at this moment.